# Restarting program from a certain point after an if

Tags: java, restart, terminate

I started studying Java not too long ago, I am currently trying to make a little game to see if I got the things I saw right.
I want to make a "game" that let's you choose between two dialogue options which have different consequences.
This is the code I used:

```
package programs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programma1_0 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(
            "You wake up in a laboratory. You don't remember ever being there. You actually don't remember anything.");
    System.out.println("A door opens, a girl comes towards you.");
    System.out.println("Girl:<<Hi, I see you woke up. How are you feeling?>>");
    System.out.println("(Write Good or Bad)");

    Scanner first = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstch = first.nextLine();

    if (firstch.equals("Good")) {
        System.out.println("Great, we have a lot to explain.");
    } else if (firstch.equals("Bad")) {
        System.out.println("You should be alright in an hour or so. You've slept for a long time.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("(I told you to write Good or Bad)");

    }



    }
}
```

So far it's working as intended. The only problem is that if I write something other than Good or Bad i get the message "(I told you to write Good or Bad)" and the program terminates. Is there a way to automatically restart it? If i put more choices in, I want the program to automatically restart from the question where it terminated (So I don't play through half of the game, get a question wrong and have to restart the program from the start), is that possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by putting this before your if statement.

```
while (true) {
     if (firstch.equals("Good") || firstch.equals("Bad")) 
         break;  
     else {
         System.out.println("(I told you to write Good or Bad)");
         firstch = first.nextLine();
     }
 }
```

Then you can also remove the last `else` part of your `if` statement.

Now it will continue asking for a new input till it gets either "Good" or "Bad"

Comment: You need an empty line between text and code, then the 4 whitespaces will work.

Comment: *"Now it will continue asking for a new input till it gets either "Good" or "Bad""* Not really, because it won't compile :P

Comment: @Tom, are you refering to the incorrect syntax such as the println? Guess i could fix it, was just trying to get the method across :P

Comment: I'm also referring to `String firstch = first.nextLine();`.

Comment: oh yeah, just copied the line, whoops :). I see you quoting my other comment, i only meant to help, as that was an important part for it to work. At first i only wrote semi-pseudo code here getting the idea across, prettying it up a little bit afterwards, forgot some things during that :P..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your `if-else` statement inside the `do-while` loop, that way you can `loop` through until you get correct response

```
int i = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("(Write Good or Bad)");
    firstch = first.nextLine();
    if (firstch.equals("Good")) {
        System.out.println("Great, we have a lot to explain.");
        i = 0;
    } else if (firstch.equals("Bad")) {
        System.out.println("You should be alright in an hour or so. You've slept for a long time.");
        i = 0
    } else {
        System.out.println("(I told you to write Good or Bad)");
        i = 1;
    }
} while (i == 1);
```

Comment: Your solution never lets the person give a new input and would just continue writing "I told you to write good or bad"

Comment: Yeah, my bad. then simply move the scanner input inside the loop as well. It is too late in the night

Answer (score 0):

You can partition your program into separate methods. Here I created a method called `retrieveAnswer()` which its only task to create a `Scanner` and get input. This method will return a `String` as seen in the `public static String` header.

Another method I created was entitled `getResult()` which takes a `String` argument and will now compare the `String` passed from

```
   String firstch = retrieveAnswer();
   getResult(firstch);
```

If the result goes to the `else` block, it will call `retrieveAnswer()` and pass the value returned to `getResult()` as seen in `getResult(retrieveAnswer())` which will then restart the whole process.

There are multiple solutions to this, but I just took the recursion route instead. Good luck with Java! If you are confused, look more into methods as they are VERY essential in programming.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Source {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(
                "You wake up in a laboratory. You don't remember ever being there. You actually don't remember anything.");
        System.out.println("A door opens, a girl comes towards you.");
        System.out.println("Girl:<<Hi, I see you woke up. How are you feeling?>>");
        System.out.println("(Write Good or Bad)");

        String firstch = retrieveAnswer();
        getResult(firstch);

    }

    public static String retrieveAnswer(){
        Scanner first = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstch = first.nextLine();
        return firstch;
    }
    public static void getResult(String firstch){
        if (firstch.equals("Good")) {
            System.out.println("Great, we have a lot to explain.");
        } else if (firstch.equals("Bad")) {
            System.out.println("You should be alright in an hour or so. You've slept for a long time.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("(I told you to write Good or Bad)");
            getResult(retrieveAnswer());
        }
    }
}
```