# Can I repeat a section of code until I get a desired answer

Tags: java

so I've been learning java in my CS class at my high school, and I decided to remake a game that was my final project last year and add a bit more to it.

My problem is that I have the player input a number in order to make a specific choice, but if they input an invalid option, the code just ends, I've found a user with a similar problem [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812722/restarting-program-from-a-certain-point-after-an-if) but they are using if/else statements, and I'm using a switch statement

```
//shows the options the player can pick
    System.out.println("Start Game: 1");
    System.out.println("Close Game: 2");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    switch(choice)
    {
        case "1": Variables.clear(); introduction(); break;
        case "2": System.exit(0);
        default: Variables.invalidAnswer();
    }

public static void introduction()
    {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

One of the answers was to try using a while(true) loop, which I tried

```
while(true)
{
    //shows the options the player can pick
    System.out.println("Start Game: 1");
    System.out.println("Close Game: 2");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    switch(choice)
    {
        case "1": Variables.clear(); introduction(); break;
        case "2": System.exit(0);
        default: Variables.invalidAnswer(); Variables.clear();
    }
}
```

but when I do that, it just loops no matter what, I thought about adding another break statement after case "1", but I realized that wouldn't work. So I was wondering if there was a way to be able to make this work, or if there was a solution like this that works with a switch statement, any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: Read up more on the `while` loop. Where you've got `true` right now, you can replace that with a condition that will become false when you're ready to stop repeating.

Comment: See [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

I'm always curious as to why people seem to forget that a `do-while` actually exists.  Consider for a moment, the overall requirement - you must perform the loop at least once, so, we don't care about the exit condition until the end of the loop, for example...

```
String exitOption = "2";
String choice = null;
do {
    System.out.println("Start Game: 1");
    System.out.println("Close Game: 2");
    choice = input.nextLine();

    switch (choice) {
        case "1":
            Variables.clear();
            introduction();
            break;
        default:
            Variables.invalidAnswer();
    }
} while (!exitOption.equals(choice));
```

Here, I'm assuming you only ever want to exit the loop when the user selects `2`, just beware of that

Flow control is a pretty basic concept of programming, you should take a closer look up:

- [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)
- [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. Case 2 just completely terminates the session,  I don't need to fix that, what I'm trying to do is make sure that when I call case 1, it doesn't loop back to asking for user input once the method called finishes.

Comment: @Logan.Ferris Well, that's up to you, but I would consider the use of `System.exit` some what of a anti pattern and you should be allowing the program to terminate after it exists the main method naturally.  This would "suggest" that when the user selects `1` you call a different method to handle the game logic and it then returns to this loop and re-prompts the user again ... "Do you want to play again?", but this is me and your needs might differ, but the basic concept is the same

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `break` inside a switch-block will break the switch-block, not the while-loop. To break the outer while-loop, you can use a label:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputLoop: while (true) {
            System.out.println("Start Game: 1");
            System.out.println("Close Game: 2");
            String choice = input.nextLine();
        
            switch(choice)
            {
                case "1": {
                    // Start the game
                    System.out.println("Game started");
                    break inputLoop;
                }
                case "2": {
                    // End the game
                    System.out.println("Game finished");
                    break inputLoop;
                }
                default: {
                    // Do nothing (the loop will be repeated)
                    System.out.println("Invalid answer");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could control your loop with a boolean variable - desiredAnswer in this case:

```
boolean desiredAnswer = false;
while(!desiredAnswer)
{
    //shows the options the player can pick
    System.out.println("Start Game: 1");
    System.out.println("Close Game: 2");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    switch(choice)
    {
        case "1": Variables.clear(); introduction(); desiredAnswer = true; break;
        case "2": System.exit(0);
        default: Variables.invalidAnswer(); Variables.clear();
    }
}
```

while loop works only when the expression returns true, so negating it would cause breaking the loop.